# Implement Server Push on an ARM Embedded Linux device

Tags: linux, webserver, arm, comet, ape

I've spent some time looking at various ways of pushing data from a web server running on a embedded linux arm platform to mulitple clients. I've looked at [APE](http://www.ape-project.org/), [Commet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29), and more but can't find anything suitable for the embedded arm linux world.

Is there an easy method to push real-time data to a web browser from a server running on embedded ARM-Linux platform? (Probably up 20 simulatanous client connections each with about 100 dynamic data points)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverlow. Please be sure to read the FAQ - particularly the section about the type of questions that are accepted by the community.   As it stands this one is very conceptual, and not really suitable for the Q&A format.

Comment: Thanks Marko, first ever question, have tried to reword as per FAQ